# Another password_verify() issue possibly database related

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

I've looked through a pile of other questions before posting. at this point i'm pretty tired of beating my head against a wall.
There seems to be an issue when moving from the signup page to the login page that is somehow related to the database.

```
class USER
{   

private $conn;

public function __construct()
{
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->dbConnection();
    $this->conn = $db;
}



public function register($fname,$l_init,$umail,$upass)
{
    try
    {
        $new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(first_name,last_initial,email,salt) 
                                                   VALUES(:fname, :l_init, :umail, :upass)");

        $stmt->bindparam(":fname", $fname);
        $stmt->bindparam(":l_init", $l_init);
        $stmt->bindparam(":umail", $umail);
        $stmt->bindparam(':upass', $new_password);                                        



        if(password_verify($upass, $new_password))
        {
            $stmt->execute();
            echo "password verify works"; //$stmt->rowCount();
        }
        else
        {
            echo "password verify is corrupt";
            sleep(5);
            die;
        }
        //$resp = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   

        /*if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
        {
            $success = "New User created! Redirecting....";
        }
        else
        {
            $success = false;
        }

        return $success;    */
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }               
}


public function doLogin($umail,$upass)
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=:umail");
        //bind params here
        $stmt->bindparam(":umail", $umail);


        $stmt->execute(); 

        echo $stmt->rowCount(); //echo if there is a returned result row

        $resp = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


// checking for any variance between single/double quotes
        $one = $resp["salt"];
        $two = $resp['salt'];

        echo "first check".$one;
        echo "<br> second check" . $two . "<br>";

        //original check for existance of a match
        if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
        {   session_start();

            echo "third check" . $upass  . '<br>';              
            echo "4th check" . password_verify($upass, $resp['salt']) . '<br>';


        echo "hash gen" . password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT) . '<br>';
        if($resp['salt'] == password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT))
            {echo "true somehow";}
        sleep(20);


            if(password_verify($upass, $resp['salt']))
            {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['user_session'] = $resp['first_name'];
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            } 
        }
        else
        {
        $e_response = "Were sorry but that email is not Registered <br> Please check your spelling and try again";
        return $e_response;
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

1)database is stored as varchar 255.
While trying to register a new user into the database results in a correct password verify test. 
however, all of my attempts to coerce password_verify to work with the doLogin function fail.

i've thrown in some clutter of echo's just to see whats actually being output.

what i see is the following:

```
first check$ 2y$10$HwC2tF1hELiqJ2QEL8Oeju1L3Ore26GSnxh6CiibPbiNwPIpVUIfi
second check $2y$10$HwC2tF1hELiqJ2QEL8Oeju1L3Ore26GSnxh6CiibPbiNwPIpVUIfi
third check  testpass    
4th check    (blank- assuming this means false? or something else?)
hash gen     $2y$10$K5j3GlqjQ7OVew9yj1FbRuF1FFin9egPVq/Uzv8D0UzsU/LKH4FDa
```

I have been up all night wondering what i could possibly be doing wrong.
I have one original database user that DOES recognize the password- however that hash was not dynamically created in an SQL query. It was created & was manually copied into the database. 
Please help

Comment: `var_dump()` your 4th check, make sure it is failing or not.

Comment: bool(false) 4th check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo password_verify("",'$2y$10$HwC2tF1hELiqJ2QEL8Oeju1L3Ore26GSnxh6CiibPbiNwPIpVUIfi')."\n";
```

returns 1.

Means $upass passed in register() was empty.

Given that mess of a code you have, no wonder it was missed somewhere.

Comment: SOB!  thank you kindly sir.   turns out i had a simple typo in my form where the variable wasn't passed & instead it was an empty string. (insert facepalm here)  I'll clean up the code now

Answer (score 0):

Some observations:

1. good for you for using password_hash instead of trying to reinvent password security.
2. You've shown us functions for `register()` and `doLogin()`, but you have not shown us how those functions are called. It seems likely that they're being called with incorrect parameters.  When debugging there's no harm in echoing or dumping the plaintext passwords to make sure you have the values you think you have.
3. each call to password_hash() with the same plaintext password is going to generate a different hashed value: password_hash() generates and uses a cryptorandom salt (to slow down cybercriminals who try to use lookup tables to crack your password system).
4. the password_verify() function returns true or false.
5. hashed passwords contain `$` characters. Therefore, if you write them as constants in php, you have to enclose them in single `'` quotes, because php attempts variable substitution in strings with double `"` quotes.

But: this is not your problem. You don't have any string constants containing hashed passwords in your program. Here you're trying to use single or double quotes in the name of an array element. That's not the context in which that choice makes a difference.

```
    $one = $resp["salt"];
    $two = $resp['salt'];
```

6. I wish your hashed-password column in your table was named `hashed_password` instead of `salt`. I experienced some minutes of confusion reading your code due to that, and you will too when you come back to this code two years from now. If somebody else maintains your code, she will curse your name for this kind of thing. This sort of code is long-lived: built it carefully.
7. Wise programmers avoid using `SELECT *`. It's much better to give the names of the columns you want. This is especially true in the early days of a system, before you add new columns to critical tables.